# joining all points inside a grouped point plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data frame like this

```
AA=
States   Clusters ncomp
HR  Cluster-1     9
HR  Cluster-2     4
HR  Cluster-3     9
WB  Cluster-1    13
WB  Cluster-2    13
WB  Cluster-3    13
WB  Cluster-4    13
TL  Cluster-1     9
TL  Cluster-2    11
TL  Cluster-3     9
TL  Cluster-4    10
TL  Cluster-5    11
TL  Cluster-6     7
OR  Cluster-1    15
OR  Cluster-2    15
OR  Cluster-3    15
OR  Cluster-4    14
OR  Cluster-5    15
OR  Cluster-6    15
```

Need to plot which looks as. I don't want to use facet_wrap.
I can create grouped point plot

[image]

Comment: Where is that plot from? Looks like you already know how to do this?

Comment: "I can create grouped point plot": you mean you're able to get that plot? So what plot do you want? Your sentence "Need to plot which looks as." isn't finished, is it? (I'm not a star in English)

Comment: no I joined the points in paint ... Not yet finished yet. I plotted grouped points need help for lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a hidden `facet_grid` and one tidyverse line to separate the `Cluster` column. This can be done also by `ave` like

```
d$C2 <- ave(as.numeric(d$Clusters),  d$States, FUN = function(x) seq(1,length(x))) 

library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  separate(Clusters, into=c("C1", "C2"), sep="-") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.numeric(C2), ncomp, color=States)) + 
   geom_vline(data = .  %>%   count(States) %>% 
                mutate(x=n/2+0.5),
              aes(xintercept=x),
              color="white")+
   geom_point() + 
   geom_line(aes(group=1)) + 
   facet_grid(~States, switch = "x",scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") + 
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL, minor_breaks = NULL, expand = c(0.2,0.5))+
   xlab("States") + 
   theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks = element_blank(),
         strip.background = element_blank(),
         panel.spacing.x= unit(0, "mm"))
```

[image]

Another approach is using an interaction term like this:

```
d %>% 
  # calculate a numeric interaction between clusters and States 
  mutate(x=as.numeric(interaction(Clusters,States))) %>%
   # calculate breaks 
   group_by(States) %>%
   mutate(xbreaks=mean(x)) %>% 
  {ggplot(.,aes(x, ncomp, color=States)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(.$xbreaks), labels = unique(.$States),minor_breaks = NULL)}
```

[image]

The fancy `{}` must be done to pipe break and label values.

Comment: bingo, worked, But can we add little space between points of two states as it looks the OR first point is just below HR, also one more query can we color them separately, with states?

Comment: @makarandkulkarni see my edits. Add some `expand = c(0.2,0.5)` and `color=States`

Comment: The second option is easy to understand, and breaks is the key, thanks Jimbou