# R ggplot changing the color and legend sequences in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, line-plot

the data in this post: [joining all points inside a grouped point plot using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648204/joining-all-points-inside-a-grouped-point-plot-using-ggplot)  remains same I have added one more column  to it. By taking help of given solution by Jimbou I wrote following code

```
head(AA)
 States Clusters   value Comp_apply L1_25 L1_30 L1_50     x xbreaks
<chr>  <chr>      <dbl>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 HR     Cluster-1 0.0703          9     2     4     7    31    32.7
2 HR     Cluster-2 0.0761          4     2     2     3    33    32.7
3 HR     Cluster-3 0.0692          9     7     7     8    34    32.7
4 WB     Cluster-1 0.0372         13     2     2     2   111   113. 
5 WB     Cluster-2 0.0762         13     2     3     6   113   113. 
6 WB     Cluster-3 0.0906         13     3     3     4   114   113.
```

now the code for plotting is

```
ggplot(data=data.m1)+
 geom_line(aes(x = x, y = Comp_apply, group=States,color="red")
           ,position=position_dodge(width = 0.90))+
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = Comp_apply, group=States,color="red")
        ,position=position_dodge(width = 0.90))+
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = L1_25, group=States,color="green")
        ,position=position_dodge(width = 0.90))+
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = L1_25, group=States,color="green")
         ,position=position_dodge(width = 0.90))
```

Now the plot looks as follows
[image]

can you help me how to rectify this

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: look at the legend and plot the red color showing name green and green showing red. see command for  "Comp_apply" plotting it should be red

Comment: Search `[ggplot2] wrong colors` to get dozen of questions about how to correctly assign colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign, as you did, a color to a whole `geom`, just put `colour="red"` outside of the `aes()`. But then the colour will not appear in legend as it is not mapped to any factor.

The correct way to do this is to modify your `data.frame` so that `Comp_apply` and `L1_25` appears as two modalities of the same factor (i.e. in the same column). I can't do it for you as your data are not provided.

Then you would have to call `geom_point` and `geom_line` only once. Provide data and I update my answer.

Comment: yes this helped me put color="red" out side aes()